# How to write a stream to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I want to write a file in gcs with a stream object but I've only found the "create_file" function that creates a new file object by providing a path to a local file to upload and the path to store it with in the bucket.

Is there any function to create a file in gcs from a stream?

Answer (score 1):

#### Fuse over GCS

You could try [gcsfuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse) which layers a [user-space fs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) over a bucket but it is only beta s/ware at present. There's a nice section on [limitations](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/semantics.md) which you should read first.

I use [fog](https://github.com/fog/fog-google) to access GCS but that is a thin layer which doesn't try to impose any additional semantics into the bucket/object model.

Warning, if your problem really requires a standard file-system underneath any possible solution then GCS is not a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to provide an IO object instead of a File object has only recently been possible. It was added in [PR 1335](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/pull/1335), and will be included in the next release.

Until then, quickest way is to write the stream to a tempfile and upload that. For more see [Issue 305](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/issues/305).